# htaccess regular expression to include ampersand

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My CMS generates URLs for articles like this:

```
/?action=viewArticleName&page_identifier=lessons
```

I've rewritten this with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-z,A-Z,0-9-]+)/?$ ?action=viewArticleName&page_identifier=$1 [L,NC]
```

Which produces `/pages/lessons` for the URL.

My problem now is to create something with an '&' or ampersand. Say:

```
/pages/terms&conditions
```

I imagine my expression `([a-z,A-Z,0-9-]+)` doesn't include these characters? 
Would someone please mind explaining if its possible to do so, and if there may be any security risk?

Suppose the security is more down to the use of preg_replace or other security measures in the article class? Please correct me if im wrong, just trying to create a simple CMS to help me get to grips with things..

Its being rueturned from the DB with the following php:

```
public static function getBypage_identifier( $page_identifier ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles WHERE page_identifier = :page_identifier";
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":page_identifier", $page_identifier, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->execute();
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    if ( $row ) return new Article( $row );
  }
```

Could it be something to do with the stripping the & out? The DB is in utf8_general_ci. And is in the page_identifier as 'terms-&-disclaimer'. Just pulling up a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pages/([a-z0-9,&-]+)/?$ ?action=viewArticleName&page_identifier=$1 [L,NC,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

btw you don't need to put comma inside character class unless you want to match literal comma also.

Comment: thanks Anubhava, looks a a lot nicer without the comma thought it was a requirement.
 It doesn't seem to be returning the correct page though. Not sure why it wouldn't, the rest of the pages without the '&' work.
Do you think it could be an issue with the character set in the DB? Im stumped..

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have other rules too?

Comment: there are some other rules:
'code'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
'code'

Comment: OK then make sure tha you place my suggested rule before your earlier rule.

Comment: thanks anubhava, I gave it a go but it's still not working. Could it be how im pulling the identifier from the DB? I have updated my question with the code. Really appreciate the help

Comment: Actually you needed `B` flag. See updated rule now in the answer.

Comment: spot on, many thanks. Will have a read up about flags.. Cheers